# Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer to test the frontend of my site. However, as I am displaying a banner in a table I get an error that

My html `table-body` looks like the following:

```
<tbody>
   <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td tabindex="0">7/9/2019</td>
      <td>Product 1</td>
      <td>Active</td>
      <td><a href="test">Category 1</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td style="width: 0; padding: 0"></td>
      <td style="width: 0; padding: 0"></td>
      <td style="width: 0; padding: 0"></td>
      <td style="width: 0; padding: 0"></td>
      <td style="width: 0; padding: 0"></td>
      <td style="width: 0; padding: 0"></td>
      <td style="width: 0; padding: 0"></td>
   </tr>
```

My page.evaluate() code looks like the following:

```
                data = await page.evaluate(async () => {
                    let data = [];
                    let grabFromRow = (row, child) => {
                        const td = row
                            .querySelector(`td:nth-child(${child})`)
                        return td ? td.innerText.trim() : null
                    }
                    let grabLinkFromRow = (row, child) => {
                        const td = row
                            .querySelector(`td:nth-child(${child}) > a`).getAttribute("href");  // here I get the error
                        return td ? td : null;
                    };

                    let rows = "#producttable > tbody > tr"

                    let tableRows = document.querySelectorAll(rows)
                    for (const tr of tableRows) {
                        data.push({
                            date: grabFromRow(tr, 1),
                            product: grabFromRow(tr, 2),
                            status: grabFromRow(tr, 3),
                            category: grabFromRow(tr, 4),
                            categoryLink: grabLinkFromRow(tr, 4),
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                });
```

Any suggestions, how to skip these emtpy rows and still execute my testing script?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: you don't have an anchor present inside td

Comment: @karthick Sorry, fixed my example above! However, the source of the error is still the same ;) Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Why -1? I fixed the anchor...

Comment: do the same thing as you do in `grabFromRow`; remove `getAttribute` from where it is and put it after `return td ? td`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Please add your suggestions as an answer! Thx in advance!

Comment: @Anna.Klee I didnt do the -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right idea in your other function, `grabFromRow`, where you set `td` to the result of `querySelector` and check it for truthiness.

```
   let grabLinkFromRow = (row, child) => {
        const td = row
            .querySelector(`td:nth-child(${child}) > a`);
        return td ? td.getAttribute("href") : null;
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to first check if `a` tag is available or not if yes then getAttribute and return else return null.

```
const td = row.querySelector(`td:nth-child(${child}) > a`);  // here I get the error
 if ( td ) {
    return td.getAttribute("href");
 }
    return null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing a chained operation in one statement can lead to this error because if any step of the chain fails, it could return `null` or `undefined`, and then any further operations attempted will fail.  In your `grabLinkFromRow` function you have this line:

```
const td = row.querySelector(`td:nth-child(${child}) > a`).getAttribute("href");
```

The problem here is that the `querySelector` is returning `null` because there are no links in the row.  That means you're trying to call `null.getAttribute("href")` and hence the error.

You should make sure you found the link before continuing like this:

```
let grabLinkFromRow = (row, child) => {
  let td;
  const link = row.querySelector(`td:nth-child(${child}) > a`);
  if (link) {   // <-- only call getAttribute if we found a link
    td = link.getAttribute("href");
  }
  return td ? td : null;
}
```